# Export plotly graph from R to self-contained HTML file programatically

Tags: r, plotly

I can export **one graph at a time** to a self-contained HTML file using RStudio's 'Export > Save as Web Page…'.

Thanks to [Sergio Oller](https://gist.github.com/zeehio/521de08708870c24f5dca478a92818c5) I can programatically export to an HTML file **with a separate `lib` directory** like this:

```
p <- plotly::plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width)

htmltools::save_html(
  html = htmltools::as.tags(
    x = plotly::toWebGL(p),
    standalone = TRUE),
  file = "test.html")
```

However I'd like to be able to export a graph to a self-contained HTML file programatically so that I then can apply the same process to export many graphs to many files.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/34580095/709777